# нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c, исключения, списки

При компиляции, в Debug выскакивает исключение

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6BF921ED2 в Проект1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
>   Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения в функции Search.

В release срабатывает все нормально. Задача такая. Нужно найти все одинаковые, подряд идущие элементы односвязного списка и заменить их одним. Пришел к выводу, что выхожу за пределы списка в цикле. но не могу понять, как этого избежать.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
void add_first(node** head, int data1)
{
    node* tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data = data1;
    tmp->next = *head;
    *head = tmp;
}


void add_last(node** head, int data1)
{
    node* tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data = data1;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (!*head) *head = tmp;
    else
    {
        node* tmp2 = *head;

        while (tmp2->next) tmp2 = tmp2->next;

        tmp2->next = tmp;
    }
}
void print_list(node* head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("[%d]->", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }

    printf("NULL\n");
}
void clean(node** head)
{
    node* tmp;

    while (*head)
    {
        tmp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int delete_first(node** head)
{
    node* prev = NULL;
    int val = 0;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return val;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        prev = *head;
        val = prev->data;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(prev);
        return val;
    }
}
node* getNth(node* head, int n)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < n && head)
    {
        head = head->next;
        counter++;
    }

    return head;
}
void add_midd(node* head, int n, int val)
{
    int i = 0;
    node* tmp = NULL;

    while (i < n && head->next)
    {
        head = head->next;
        i++;
    }

    tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data = val;

    if (head->next)
    {
        tmp->next = head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }

    head->next = tmp;
}
int delete_n(node** head, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return delete_first(head);
    }
    else
    {
        node* prev = getNth(*head, n - 1);
        node* elm = prev->next;
        int val = elm->data;
        prev->next = elm->next;
        free(elm);
        return val;
    }
}


bool companator(node* head_1)
{
    bool b = false;

    if (head_1->data == head_1->next->data)
    {
        b = true;
    }

    return b;
}




void search(node** head)
{
    int counter = 0;
    node* tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    tmp = *head;

    while (tmp->next)
    {
        if (companator(tmp) == true)
        {
            delete_n(head, counter);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
void voidsymbal(node* head)
{
    int a = 0;
    int num;
    printf("Если хотите ввести эллемент в список нажмите Enter если хотите выйти Esc\n");
    unsigned key = _getch();

    if ((key == 0) || (key == 224))
        key = _getch();

    if (key == 13)
    {
loop2:
        system("cls");
        printf("Если хотите ввести эллемент в начало списка нажмите 1\n");
        printf("Если хотите ввести эллемент в конец списка нажмите 2\n");
        printf("Если хотите ввести эллемент в середину списка нажмите 3\n");
        printf("Если хотите удалить элемент нажмите 4\n");
        printf("Чтобы заменить повторяющиеся элементы нажмите 5\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &a);

        switch (a)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                printf("Введите число: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &num);
                add_first(&head, num);
                break;

            case 2:
                system("cls");
                printf("Введите число: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &num);
                add_last(&head, num);
                break;

            case 3:
                int k;
                system("cls");
                printf("Введите после какого эллемента вставить: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &k);
                system("cls");
                printf("Введите число: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &num);
                add_midd(head, k, num);
                break;

            case 4:
                system("cls");
                printf("Введите какой элемент удалить: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &num);
                system("cls");
                delete_n(&head, num);
                break;

            case 5:
                system("cls");
                search(&head);
                // search(&head);
                break;
        }

        print_list(head);
        printf("Если хотите продолжить нажмите Enter,если нет Esc");
        unsigned key2 = _getch();

        if ((key2 == 0) || (key2 == 224))
            key2 = _getch();

        if (key2 == 13)
        {
            system("cls");
            goto loop2;
        }

        if (key2 == 27)
        {
            system("cls");
            goto loop;
        }
    }

    if (key == 27)
    {
loop:
        system("cls");
        printf("До свидания");
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    node* head = NULL;
    voidsymbal(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next; // struct где?
};

Comment: зачем? мы же объявили тип.

Comment: Вы на си, или на c++ пишете? Не вижу typedef.

Comment: на си,извиняюсь не указал в теме

Comment: Зачем мне тут typedef??? можно пожалуйста по теме...

Comment: @Yami, ну что тут не понятно, человек пишет в стиле Си, компилирует компилятором C++, поэтому без `struct` и без `typedef`)

Comment: Соберите с ключем -g и посмотрите значения переменных в отладчике